# Can spring webclient be used with RESTful API which is not reactive based?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Is there any issues with using WebClient for fetching responses from multiple REST APIs which are not reactive based.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you definitely can, and in fact, the use of WebClient is encouraged by Spring officially. Also, the RestTemplate which is generally the preferred way of communication for REST-based services has already been deprecated.

Also, there are no issues when using WebClient in a non-reactive context

[image]

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#webmvc-client

However, you'll explicitly have to call `subscribe` or `block` when using WebClient in a non-reactive context.

Comment: Thanks. So what all benefits are lost when using this way? compared to using webclient with a reactive API.

Comment: You do not lose any benefits of WebClient even when using it in a non-reactive environment.

Comment: Isnt the async and non-blocking implementation only available in reactive world? This is why I asked.

Comment: @Isank please read the part https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about images, `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.`